# If condition for new column in Pandas is not met, use value above

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a Pandas Dataframe which looks (in Excel) like:

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPCj2.png)

The formula in column F is: =IF(ISBLANK(E7),F7,((D8-E7)/D8)*F7)

Translating it into Python causes some troubles. The following code does not fill the rest of the column with the calculated factor.

```
hdax_aktien['RHMG.TG']['Adjust'] = np.where(np.isnan(hdax_aktien['RHMG.TG'].iloc[:,5])==True, hdax_aktien['RHMG.TG']['Adjust'].shift() ,((hdax_aktien['RHMG.TG']['CLOSE']-hdax_aktien['RHMG.TG'].iloc[:,5])/hdax_aktien['RHMG.TG']['CLOSE'])*hdax_aktien['RHMG.TG']['Adjust'].shift())
```

So my question is:
Is the shift operator the appropriate way to deal with my problem or should I use apply or iterows?

Edit:
The Dataframe should look like (I defined the last column as a columns of 1 before executing the code above):

```
2913  148124 2019-05-24  RHMG.TG  111.594041   99.620                             NaN  1.000000
2914  148125 2019-05-27  RHMG.TG  111.556461   99.640                             NaN  1.000000
2915  148126 2019-05-28  RHMG.TG  111.599670  100.000                             NaN  1.000000
2916  148127 2019-05-29  RHMG.TG  107.239441   96.360                            2.10  0.978207
2917  148128 2019-05-30  RHMG.TG  107.961312   97.000                             NaN  0.978207
2918  148129 2019-05-31  RHMG.TG  106.532663   95.400                             NaN  0.978207
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Could you please print an example dataframe? It's not very clear how the data is supposed to be filled and normalised

Comment: I added a dataframe, as I would expect it. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping it simple, you could recreate the excel formula on a function and apply a lambda over the dataframe (if your aim is to calculate it over each row on the dataframe)

```py
def calculation(E,F,D):
    if np.isnan(E):
        return F
    else:
        return ((D - E) / D)*F

db['Adjust'] = db.apply(
    lambda row: calculation(row['E'], row['F'], row['D']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not digging into the details, I would normally use .at[index, column name] for such issue. You can use np.where() just to get indexes that satisfy your logical conditions and put this index into .at[]

Answer (score 0):

Split your task in two steps:

1. Fill `nan` values with the values of the next column
2. Normalise

Assuming the column names in your excel file, something like this should give you what you want:

```py
def normalise(row):
    return (row['CLOSE'] - row['prev_CLOSE']) / row['CLOSE'] * row['Adjust.Factor']

data['Div'] = data['Div'].fillna(data['Adjust.Factor'])
data['prev_CLOSE'] = data['CLOSE'].shift()
data['norm'] = data.apply(normalise, axis=1)
```